# Togaf 9.1 architecture Vision -

Tags: togaf, enterprise-architecture

Apologies for this specific question, but need to understand below as am trying to understand the rationale behind the steps, please help.

**From TOGAF 9.1 Document:**

**7.4.3 Confirm and Elaborate Business Goals, Business Drivers, and Constraints**

*Identify the business goals and strategic drivers of the organization.
If these have already been defined elsewhere within the enterpr ise, ensure that the existing
definitions are current, and clarify any areas of ambiguity. **Otherwise, go back to the originators
of the Statement of Architecture Work** and work with them to define these essential items and
secure their endorsement by cor porate management.
.*.....

**Question**:

Shouldnt it be - ***Go back to Sponsors or Request for Architecture Work document*** as the Statement of Architecture Work is not yet started at this point?

**Reference: Arch Vision Steps**

7.4.1 - Establish the architecture project

7.4.2 - Identify stakeholders, concer ns, and business requirements

7.4.3 - **Confirm and elaborate business goals, business drivers, and constraints**

7.4.4 - Evaluate business capabilities

7.4.5 - Assess readiness for business transformation

7.4.6 - Define scope

7.4.7 - Confirm and elaborate Architecture Principles, including business principles

7.4.8 - Develop Architecture Vision

7.4.9 - Define the Target Architecture value propositions and KPIs

7.4.10-Identify the business transfor mation risks and mitigation activities

7.4.11 - **Develop Statement of Architecture Work; secure approval**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, this does not make sense. To my understanding of TOGAF, it should be "go back to the originators of the **Request for Architecture Work**".

As you noticed yourself, the Statement of Architecture Work is not an input, but an output of phase A. The Request for Architecture Work on the other hand is an input and should contain the business goals.